# ComplexModel not available on the client

Tags: spyne

I just started using Spyne and tried to use a ComplexModel as a parameter for one method. I mostly followed the user_manager example from the sources with spyne<2.99 but I always get a type error when doing the client.factory.create() call.

Example code that fails:

```
from spyne.application import Application
from spyne.decorator import rpc
from spyne.service import ServiceBase
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.model.primitive import String, Integer
from spyne.model.complex import ComplexModel

class DatosFac(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = 'facturamanager.datosfac'
    numero = String(pattern=r'[A-Z]/[0-9]+')

class FacturaService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(String, DatosFac, _returns=Integer)
    def updateFacData(self, numero, data):
        # do stuff
        return 1

application = Application([FacturaService], 'facturaManager.service',
        in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
        out_protocol=Soap11()
    )

from spyne.server.null import NullServer
s = NullServer(application)
data = s.factory.create('DatosFac')
```

If you run this code you get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spyner.py", line 25, in <module>
    data = s.factory.create('DatosFac')
  File "/Users/marc/.pyEnvs/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyne/client/_base.py", line 30, in create
    return self.__app.interface.get_class_instance(object_name)
  File "/Users/marc/.pyEnvs/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyne/interface/_base.py", line 114, in get_class_instance
    return self.classes[key]()
KeyError: 'DatosFac'
```

(I used NullServer to make it easier to reproduce, but the same happens over Soap+Wsgi).

I amb pretty much stuck at this as I don't see what's essentialy different from this code and the user_manager examples.

What am I doing wrong?

thanks,
marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing a fully working example.

The difference is that tns and the namespace of the DatosFac are different.

Either do:

```
data = s.factory.create('{facturamanager.datosfac}DatosFac')
```

or remove `__namespace__` from `DatosFac` definition